# Why can't I execute the recursion in bubble sort

Tags: python, recursion, bubble-sort

I want to use the recursion in bubble sort algorithm, however the result shows that the function "bu_sort" haven't been used recursively. I have worked on this issue for a long time, really don't know where is the problem.

```
def bu_sort(input_list):
    print("start")
    length = len(input_list)
    print(length)
    for i in range(length - 2):
        print("times")
        if input_list[i] > input_list[i + 1]:
            tem = input_list[i + 1]
            input_list[i + 1] = input_list[i]
            input_list[i] = tem
    bu_sort(input_list[:length - 2])

test1 = [7,4,2,8,5,1]       
bu_sort(test1)
print(test1)
```

The following is the output, only print one "start" so I know the function has been execute for only one time

```
test1 = [7,4,2,8,5,1]       
bu_sort(test1)
start 
6
times
times
times
times

print(test1)
[4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 1]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you're running? I'm getting `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, which makes sense, because your recursion never terminates.

Comment: I think OP is missing a base case. Do something like `if len(input_list) < 2: return`. I was able to replicate OP's output by adding that block inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes. First, as I mentioned in comment, you are missing a base case for this recursion. Secondly, when you do something like `a = b[:index]`, `a` is actually a new list in Python so you are passing a copy, not a reference, into your recursive call (please someone correct me if I am wrong about this). Fixing both mistakes gives the following code.

```
def bu_sort(input_list):
    return bu_sort_with_length(input_list, len(input_list))

def bu_sort_with_length(input_list, length):
    if (length < 2):
        return
    print("start")
    for i in range(length - 1):
        print("times")
        if input_list[i] > input_list[i + 1]:
            tem = input_list[i + 1]
            input_list[i + 1] = input_list[i]
            input_list[i] = tem
    bu_sort_with_length(input_list, length - 1)

test3 = [7]       
bu_sort(test3)
print(test3)

test2 = [7,4]       
bu_sort(test2)
print(test2)

test1 = [7,4,2,8,5,1]       
bu_sort(test1)
print(test1)
```

Output:

```
[7]
start
times
[4, 7]
start
times
times
times
times
times
start
times
times
times
times
start
times
times
times
start
times
times
start
times
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What you said about my original code is totally right. and about the second point, I try to modify my code follow "a = b[:length -1 ]" style, and get  a wired answer which I post in this question

Comment: @D_scientist If this answer helped you, consider accepting it